# Which one of these two technologies would be more difficult to create: matter replicators or matter teleportation?

Tags: teleportation, quantum

It seems logical that would be more difficult to create a new object out of nothing  rather than scanning all an object or a person particles and atoms and then transferring them into another location using quantum entranglement or something similar. So I think matter replication is more difficult. A replicator device would have to have stored in its computer all the positions and features of all the particles and atoms that object that is gonna be created is made of. It would have also to store the kinds of chemical elements that this stuff is made of as well.

But I read in other articles that teleportation would actually be more tricky, even more difficult teleporting people. Because the teleported object would have all its particles and atoms in the exact position and state before the teleportation have occurred. And the impenetrability of matter law say that no electrons or other fermion particles(which atoms are made of) can have the same spin, so the teleporter computer would have to be so powerful that it would have the capability of scanning not only all the particles that makeup the object or person but all its spin and other features that are inherent to particles like electric charge. But I think a quantum computer that would have millions of qubits could handle this job easily.

An interesting and important detail is that technically speaking, the two technologies appears to be the same thing but they have different objectives.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: There are more than 10^27 atoms in the human body. A million qubits of memory in your quantum computer would seem to be a vast under-estimate in this case. Other than that detail - +1 Perhaps you could tell us a little about the worldbuilding context?

Comment: Considering that both are sci-fi techniques, I see no solid basis for answers which are objective. This question is strongly opinion based and I doubt it fits our standards. We are not a forum.

Comment: You're asking us to decide which of two non-existent technologies would be simpler to invent.  Anyone who could legitimately answer that question would be running for the patent office rather than explaining why they're right.

Answer (score 1):

If by teleportation, you means Star Trek style transporter, that would be exceedingly harder.  One reason is that when you replicate something, it does not need to be alive, you just need to use a bunch of repeating patterns of atoms and molecules in generally the right places.  Using a method similar to JPEG compression, a relatively small file could contain enough information to synthesize all the proteins, carbohydrates, lipids, etc to make your fried chicken meal.  But to reassemble a human like he was before you took him apart, you need to know where each and every atom was, or else you'll be destroying memories, creating cancerous DNA, triggering seizures, etc.

Another reason replication is easier is that you have a contained system to build in.  This may not seem like a big deal, but consider this: Is it easier to print on a page that you feed through a printer, or by spraying ink onto a sheet of paper across the room?

At the end of the day, transporters are far less realistic than replicators.  That said, there may be other ways to transport a person that does not require spitting their disassembled atoms through space.  If instead, you had a device that could just make a man-sized wormhole more like stargate style teleportation, then you don't need to worry about your subject's atomic structure at all.

In this case I'd say the difficulties may be more similar, but I'd still put money on replication as the easier tech because we already have the foundational technologies behind them with 3d printers. We just need to do that, but way better to make a replicator. In contrast, we don't even know enough to prove if a wormhole can be made at all.